# Waiting for the response of several promises in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, promise, rsvp.js

I'm trying to make 3 API calls and then return an array of all the data. However, the console.log() (and therefore the function return) is empty as it's not waiting for the AJAX call to be resolved - but I can't do it in the loop as I need all the data.

```
let data = [];

parameters.forEach((parameter, index) => {
  return Ember.$.ajax(url).then((response) => {
    data.push({
      name: parameter.get('displayName'),
      color: parameter.get('color'),
      type: chart.get('chartType'),
      turboThreshold: 0,
      data: response.data
    });
  });
});

console.log(data);
return data;
```

I think that I can use Ember.RSVP.hash() for this but I can't seem to get it to work... can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `parameters` is an array, yes?

Comment: Yes it's an array of objects returned through an Ember hasMany relationship

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a promise and resolve it when all of the inner promises are resolved. I didn't try out the code, But this should point you how to proceed.

```
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) { //return a promise
    let promises = [];
    let data = [];

    parameters.forEach((parameter, index) => {
       promises[index] = Ember.$.ajax(url).then((response) => { //store all inner promises
        data.push({
          name: parameter.get('displayName'),
          color: parameter.get('color'),
          type: chart.get('chartType'),
          turboThreshold: 0,
          data: response.data
        });
      });
    });

    Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(){
        resolve(data); //resolve the promise when all inner promises are resolved
    });
});
```

Comment: if one of the promises fails will it still call the .then or all ? or will it go to .catch of all?

Comment: check the second example from this link - https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/Promise/methods/all?anchor=all

Comment: also check out https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/functions/rsvp/allSettled for your case

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't wait for promises unless you are in the routes' model hooks.
See model hooks on [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/)

You have another option, try to set data directly to the item when data is resolved. (inside the *then* function)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
return Promise.all(parameters.map(parameter => Ember.$.ajax(url).then(response => {
    'name': parameter.get('displayName'),
    'color': parameter.get('color'),
    'type': chart.get('chartType'),
    'turboThreshold': 0,
    'data': response.data
}))).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
});
```